# Passing a function in onChanged Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having these 4 `inputs` (TextFormFields) , and I want to handle a change that whenver the user changes what is written inside , a function is triggered and updates the sum of another `TextFormField`.

I thought using the `onChanged` is the best way to handle these changes , but I'm unable to make it.

I have a `TextEditingController` that I want to update whenever there is a change in the `inputs` :

```
  TextEditingController totalDocument;   





  void _CalculTotal() {

  setState(() {
  total = total + double.tryParse(widget.controllers.last.text);
  totalDocument.text = total.toString();
   });
```

}
These are my inputs inside a class :

```
        class InputRefNomProduit extends StatefulWidget {
  final String label, label2, label3, label4;
  final String content, content2, content3, content4;
  var fieldController = TextEditingController();
  var fieldController2 = TextEditingController();
  var fieldController3 = TextEditingController();
  var fieldController4 = TextEditingController();
  final FunctionStringCallback Prix;
  FormFieldValidator<String> fieldValidator = (_) {};
  InputRefNomProduit(
      {this.label,
      this.content,
      this.label2,
      this.content2,
      this.label3,
      this.content3,
      this.label4,
      this.content4,
      this.fieldController,
      this.fieldController2,
      this.fieldValidator,
      this.fieldController3,
      this.fieldController4,
      **this.Prix**});
       . . .
Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.7,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            child: TextFormField(
              **onChanged: widget.Prix,**
              enabled: true,
              controller: widget.fieldController4,
              validator: widget.fieldValidator,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                hintText: "${widget.content4}",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 190, 190),
                    fontSize: 14),
                fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The variable `Prix` is used to get the function `_CalculTotal()`.

This is my sum `TextFormField` that will hold the total :

```
SizedBox(
                              width: 200,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  **controller: totalDocument,**
                                  
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    enabled: false,
                                    hintText: '$total',
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                    ),
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                                        Icons.attach_money_outlined,
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          width: 1,
                                          color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                    ),
                                    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          width: 1,
                                          color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                    ),
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                        width: 1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                        width: 1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                        width: 1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    contentPadding:
                                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the addListener() method of your TextEditingController to listen to changes in the TextFormFields where you assigned your TextEditingController as a controller.

Checkout this flutter cookbook article for more details. It clearly explains the difference between setting the onChanged attribute of a TextFormField and using the addListener() of a controller to handle changes in your TextFields.

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes